# Django CommandError: App 'polls' has migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration, manage.py

Trying to follow the tutorial at [Django project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/).

The problem I've come across is that when performing the command:
`python manage.py sql polls` I'm given the error:

> CommandError: App 'polls' has migrations. only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations

So far I can't seem to find any guide on the internet, or this website for a solution to the program.

Comment: Are you sure you are using django 1.6? What is the value of `INSTALLED_APPS` settings? Thanks.

Comment: Im using django 1.8 right now, is 1.6 that needed?
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls'
)

Comment: I got this error running the [PyCharm Django tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html) with Django 1.7.2, where the tutorial currently assumes Django 1.6.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Django 1.8` while going through 1.6 tutorial. Pay attention to the first words at the beginning of the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/):

> This tutorial is written for Django 1.6 and Python 2.x. If the Django
>   version doesn’t match, you can refer to the tutorial for your version
>   of Django by using the version switcher at the bottom right corner of
>   this page, or update Django to the newest version.

In your case, either downgrade to 1.6, or use the [tutorial for the development (currently 1.8) version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 31):

You can either run `python manage.py makemigration` followed by `python manage.py migrate` or just delete migrations folder

Comment: What is the migrations folder for?  What is a **migration** in this context?

Comment: the command is python manage.py makemigrations not makemigration

Answer (score 3):

Simply delete folder `app-name/migrations`.

In `Django 1.7` and `Python 3.4` the solution I found is to delete this folder and everything works now.

Comment: This is kludgy at best. Migrations are an integral part of Django, and you should learn to work with them, not just delete stuff and hope for the best.

Comment: Although eykanal is right, I had similar problem and this is simply the fastest answer. Sometimes hacking works and makes your life easier. *Sometimes.*

Answer (score 0):

With django 1.7, instead of deleting app-name/migrations folder, In your MIGRATION_MODULES entry of your site, you can rename the application dictionary value with an non-existing module name by adding some dummy string:

MIGRATION_MODULES['my_app'] += '_xx'

And then manage.py sqlclear my_app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.8, you should  run another command--makemigrations [your app name]:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

You should see something similar to the following:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Choice
    - Add field question to choice
```